# Why is an unchanged file appearing in my pull request?

Tags: git, azure-devops, diff

I am working on an entity framework core project, where one of the files is the `DbContextSnapshot`

In my latest PR (to dev branch), that file appears in the 'files' section, as if there has been some change to it

However when viewing that file in the PR, there are no changes highlighted, and no changes previewed in the scroll-bar  (usually red/green blocks appear here)

When clicking on the containing folder on the left, it displays a message

> The file differs only in whitespace.

But I have selected this filter already, and no whitespace changes are shown

[image]

---

After checking out the branch and executing

```
$ git diff dev
```

I can see this for the file in question (I have no idea what it means)

```
diff --git a/Project/Migrations/DbContextSnapshot.cs b/Project/Migrations/DbContextSnapshot.cs
index d93acebd..4be2a955 100644
--- a/Project/Migrations/DbContextSnapshot.cs
+++ b/Project/Migrations/DbContextSnapshot.cs   
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@                                          
-// <auto-generated />                                                                                            
+// <auto-generated />                                                                                              
    using System;                                                                                                      
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

what gives?

Comment: Use a Hex-Editor and take a look. I would guess `LF` instead of `CRLF`?

Comment: Oh and btw: Do not put "auto-generated" files under version control.

Comment: Second guess: UTF-8 BOM?

Comment: @SebDieBln You are correct, it had somehow changed from UTF-8 to UTF-8 BOM, which I verified in notepad++, if you post an answer I will accept it

Comment: If I had $10 for every time I've seen code bomb due to the BOM, I could buy at least a nice steak dinner.

Comment: @TTT: To me, the  really funny thing is that the BOM has no function: a byte order mark in UTF-16 tells you the byte order, but in UTF-8 there is no such thing as byte order: there is only one way to read the file. One can argue that it demonstrates that the file is in fact UTF-8, but one should generally *assume* a file is UTF-8 unless told otherwise, so I find that a pretty poor excuse. :-)

Comment: @torek I had a BOM problem just last week so it's still fresh in my mind. Someone appended a script with a BOM to another script so the BOM was in the middle of the file, which made it hard(er) to discover. During troubleshooting I noticed when at the first character of the line in question (which caused a syntax error in SQL), I had to press the left arrow key twice to go back to the previous line, meaning there was an invisible character there that took up no space. So, notepad++ with "show" special characters enabled didn't help, but viewed in hex you could see it. 30 minutes wasted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The file differs only in whitespace.

This can also be triggered by the **UTF-8 BOM** being added or removed.